# How do we rigorously prove that for $n>1$, $(1+x)^{n-1}<1$ for $-1<x<0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, inequality

Given $n>1$ and

$$(1+x)^{n-1}<1$$

Intuitively I can see that for $x \in (-1,0)$, we have $1+x<1$, and if we raise that to any power then it will be smaller than 1. How do we prove this rigorously?

For context on how I came upon this question, the following is a problem from Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 11 on "Significance of Derivatives".

> 65. Use derivatives to prove that if $n \geq 1$, then
>
> $$(1+x)^n > 1+nx, \text{ for } -1<x<0 \text{ and } x>0$$
>
> (notice that equality holds for $x=0$)

The solution in the solution manual is a bit terse

> Let $g(x)=(1+x)^n-(1+nx)$. Then $g(0)=0$, but $$g'(x)=n(1+x)^{n-1}-n\tag{1}$$
>
> Since $n-1 \neq 0$ this means that
>
> $$\begin{align}g'(x) & < 0 \text{ for } -1<x<0, \\ & >0 \text{ for }
>  x>0 \end{align}\tag{2}$$
>
> Thus $g(x)>0$ for $-1<x<0$ and $x>0$

I've been reading this book as a self-contained exposition of mathematical concepts that build upon one another chapter by chapter.

I can't recall among the theorems I've seen so far a justification for the step from $(1)$ to $(2)$.

What theorem(s) justifies making this step?

In particular, we reach

$$(1+x)^{n-1}<1$$

Answer (score 1):

By induction:

For $n=2$, $-1<x<0$ hence $1+x<1$, that is $(1+x)^{2-1}<1^{2-1}=1$.

For $n+1$, $(1+x)^{n}=(1+x)^{n-1}(1+x)<(1+x)^{n-1}\cdot 1$ as we've just showed above, then $(1+x)^{n}=(1+x)^{n-1}(1+x)<(1+x)^{n-1}\cdot 1\le 1$ by induction.

Comment: There's a typo in the case $n=2$

Comment: Thank you, edited